# Multiplayer Following Camera in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, camera, multiplayer

For a school project I am building a recreation of Among Us in python with Pygame. I have already set up all the server and client side code and that's all working fine. I'm now in the process of making the camera follow the player. Only I can't get it to work.

My idea was: when a player moves, everything in his surroundings has to move in the opposite direction. But when you have a multiplayer game this doesn't work. Because then the other player moves as well which breaks the system.

If anyone has any idea how to make such a code, please let me know.
Thank you in advance

Comment: You don't need to move objects themselves, you only need to draw objects in at offsetted location. Instead of "screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft)", do "screen.blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect.topleft+camera_position)".

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to move the background and object rects around the player, you can just move the player around and have a scroll offset value that keeps track of how much the blitted objects have to be offset. You don't apply the scroll value to the rect position because the rect position isn't relative to the window like the blit objects are. Here is an example of how you could achieve this.

```py
import pygame, sys

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Scrolling example")
WINDOW_SIZE = (600, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)

scroll = [0, 0]
player = pygame.Rect(100, 100, 10, 10)
up = False
down = False
left = False
right = False

blocks = [pygame.Rect(250,250,50,50)]

while True:
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    scroll[0] += (player.x - scroll[0] - (WINDOW_SIZE[0]/2)) // 20
    scroll[1] += (player.y - scroll[1] - (WINDOW_SIZE[1]/2)) // 20

    player_movement = [0, 0]
    if right == True:
        player_movement[0] += 2
    if left == True:
        player_movement[0] -= 2
    if up == True:
        player_movement[1] -= 2
    if down == True:
        player_movement[1] += 2

    player.x += player_movement[0]
    player.y += player_movement[1]

    player_scroll_rect = player.copy()
    player_scroll_rect.x -= scroll[0]
    player_scroll_rect.y -= scroll[1]

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), player_scroll_rect)

    for block in blocks:
        scroll_block = block.copy()
        scroll_block.x = scroll_block.x - scroll[0]
        scroll_block.y = scroll_block.y - scroll[1]
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), scroll_block)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if event.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

If you want a solution for using images, ask me.
Also, you can find more about scrolling here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q7tmIlXROg